# need to get unmatched records from these 2 lists/tables using linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql

### Using these 2 tables:

```
employee(id, name)
payroll(name, salary)
```

### I need to modify & convert this SQL query to linq:

```
SELECT employee.id, employee.name, payroll.salary
FROM employee left OUTER JOIN payroll
ON employee.name like payroll.name + '%'
```

to get unmatched records from those 2 tables. Any idea?

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help ) it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
var query = from emp in context.employee
            join res in (from emp in context.employee
                         from pay in context.payroll
                         where emp.name.StartsWith(pay.name)
                         select new
                         {
                             emp.id,
                             pay.salary
                         })
            on emp.id equals res.id into subRes
            from sub in subRes.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                emp.id,
                emp.name,
                sub?.salary
            };
```

Comment: Thanks Slava. I will try it out and get back.